# Change color of the plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've got this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for (i,j) in selected:
      plt.plot([plants_points[i][0],customers_points[j][0]], [plants_points[i][1],customers_points[j][1]], 'r-')
```

However, I would like the function that is represented to have a different color for each `i`. For example if `i = 1` it is red and it is shown with a line (`r-`) if `i = 2` it is blue and it is shown with a line (`b-`), etc. The problem is that I do not have a defined range, that is,  `i` can take as many values as the user wants. Is there any way to achieve it? Thanks.

Comment: Create a list with pre-set colors (`colors = ['r-', 'b-', ...]`) and access it cyclically with `i`? `colors[i % len(colors)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`selected` is a list of tuples `(i, j)` and you want a different colour for each value of `i`. Each value of `i` may occur many times in `selected`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Use a colormap to generate an arbitrary number of colours 
cmap = plt.get_cmap('jet')

# Get the unique values for i, and assign a colour to each one
i_values = set([s[0] for s in selected])
i_colours = {i: cmap(idx / len(i_values)) for idx, i in enumerate(i_values)}

# When plotting, choose the colour by looking up i in i_colours:
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
for i, j in selected:
    colour = i_colours[i]
    ax.plot([0, 1], [j, j], '-', c=colour)
```

If you know a bit more about the values of `i` which will occur you might be able to avoid the dictionary. For example, if you know that `i` is reasonably well spread between its minimum and maximum values then you could do this instead:

```py
# Use a colormap to generate an arbitrary number of colours 
cmap = plt.get_cmap('jet')

# Get the unique values for i, and assign a colour to each one
i_values = set([s[0] for s in selected])
i_min = min(i_values)
i_max = max(i_values)

# When plotting, choose the colour by calculating its position in cmap:
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
for i, j in selected:
    colour = cmap((i - i_min) / (i_max - i_min))
    ax.plot([0, 1], [j, j], '-', c=colour)
```

The choice of which colormap to use can be hard - if the value of `i` has meaning then sequential colormaps are useful, if you want to be better able to distinguish nearby values then consider something like `'flag'`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but ussing what you've said i've this problem: i have a lot of differents colors for differents j. I want that, for example: (i,j)=(1,0) has the same color than (1,3) because it i is the same although j is different. But ussing what you have said (1,0) has different color than (1,3). I don't know if I have explained myself

Comment: Sorry. Too much code for a comment, so I've aded something above. If that helps I'll tidy up the response a bit. Do you care about the order of colours?

Comment: Thanks for answer, it was helpul ^^

Comment: Good. I've tidied it up - let me know if you need anything else.